# Multiple V-model Javascript Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to bind two functions here into one HTML element. Bellow the code of Vue function

```
var table_content = new Vue({
    el: '#table_content',
    data: {
        arr: [],
        _arr_original: [],
        price: 0,
    },
    created(){
        // some stuff here
    },
    methods:{
        change(index,index1){
            arr = this.arr[index]
            arr.total = arr.data[index1].Koef * arr.data[index1].harga_satuan
            Vue.set(this.arr,index,arr)
        }
    },
    computed:{
        modify_price:{
            get(){
                return this.price.toLocaleString()
            },
            set(value){
                var v = parseInt(value.replace(/,/g,''))
                isNaN(v) ? "" : this.price = v;
            }
        },
    }
})
```

HTML element

```
<table class="tableizer-table table-hover" id="table_content">
    <thead>
       <td>
            <div class="handsontableInputHolder">
                <textarea tabindex="-1" name="uom" class="handsontableInput area-custom val2 text-center" style="" v-model="data.harga_satuan modify_price" v-on:keyup="change(0,index)"></textarea>
            </div>
            {{-- <input name="txtEmmail" class="val2"/> --}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="handsontableInputHolder">
                <textarea tabindex="-1" name="total" class="handsontableInput area-custom multTotal text-center" disabled style="">@{{ data.Koef * data.harga_satuan }}</textarea>
            </div>
        </td>
    //..
```

The idea is I want to bind function `change` and `modify_price`. So here are the detail

```
Function `change` will handle any input from user and count a total on HTML DOM `total`

Function `modify_price` will `get` input from user (number) and auto number formating with comma that input. In other hands function set will convert text with comma and turns into number.
```

So how I can running that code simmulteanously and binding both of function? I have check from this [github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4946#issuecomment-280457589) that

> Component v-model is designed for single value input components that attend to similar use cases for native input elements.
>
> For a complex component that manages the synchronization of more than
>   one values, explicit prop/event pairs is the proper solution. In this
>   particular case I don't think the saved keystrokes are worth the added
>   complexity of additional syntax.

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day doing some research, I found a solution to have 2 v-model in one HTML DOM. Here are my solution

1. First, we need vue.component with v-model binded to computed parameter

   ```
   Vue.component('number-input', {
       props: ["value"],
       template: `
           <div>
               <input type="textarea" class="val2 bhnPrice alatPrice handsontableInput area-custom text-center text-bold" v-model="displayValue" @blur="isInputActive = false" @focus="isInputActive = true"/>
           </div>`,
       data: function() {
           return {
               isInputActive: false
           }
       },
       computed: {
           displayValue: {
               get: function() {
                   if (this.isInputActive) { 
                       return this.value.toString()
                   } else { 
                       return this.value.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?:\.\d+)?$)/g, "$1,")
                   }
               },
               set: function(modifiedValue) { 
                   let newValue = parseFloat(modifiedValue.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "")) 
                   if (isNaN(newValue)) {
                       newValue = 0
                   } 
                   this.$emit('input', newValue)
               }
           }
       }
   });
   ```
2. Second, change HTML DOM as bellow

   ```
   <div class="handsontableInputHolder">
       <number-input style="" v-model="data.harga_satuan" v-on:keyup="change(2,index)"></number-input>
   </div>
   ```